# How do I refresh jsp's on weblogic

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I'm running an exploded war on weblogic 10.0 in production mode.

I want to modify a jsp without having to fully redeploy the application. I can't seem to achieve this using the weblogic.Deployer with a partial redployment - see:

[http://download-llnw.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/deployment/redeploy.html#wp1025739](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/deployment/redeploy.html#wp1025739)

This must be a fairly standard problem - has anyone got a solution?

Comment: Are you getting an error. Is your war part of an ear? Can you post the syntax of the full command you are using.

Answer (score 5):

According to the link you have provided, `weblogic.Deployer` is your friend:

> ### Updating Static Files in a Deployed Application
>
> In a production environment, you may
>   occasionally need to refresh the
>   static content of a Web application
>   module—HTML files, image files, JSPs,
>   and so forth—without redeploying the
>   entire application. If you deployed a
>   Web application or an Enterprise
>   Application as an exploded archive
>   directory, you can use the
>   weblogic.Deployer utility to update
>   one or more changed static files
>   in-place. See <strike>[Avoiding Unnecessary
>   JSP Compilation](http://dev2dev.bea.com/pub/a/2005/01/jsp_reloaded.html) on
>   dev2dev.com</strike>[Tuning Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/perform/webapptune.html#wp1141919).
>
> To redeploy a single file associated
>   within a deployment unit, specify the
>   file name at the end of the redeploy
>   command. For example:
>
> ```
> java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://localhost:7001 -user weblogic
>    -password weblogic -name myApp -redeploy myApp/copyright.html
> ```
>
> Always specify the pathname to updated
>   files relative to the root directory
>   of the exploded archive directory. In
>   the above example, the Web application
>   is deployed as part of an Enterprise
>   Application, so the module directory
>   is specified (`myApp/copyright.html`).
>
> If the Web application module had been
>   deployed as a stand-alone module,
>   rather than as part of an Enterprise
>   Application, the file would have been
>   specified alone (`copyright.html`).
>
> You can also redeploy an entire
>   directory of files by specifying a
>   directory name instead of a single
>   file. For example:
>
> ```
> java weblogic.Deployer -adminurl http://localhost:7001 -user weblogic
>    -password weblogic -name myApp -redeploy myApp/myjsps
> ```
>
> In the above example, all files and
>   subdirectories located in the myjsps
>   subdirectory of the Enterprise
>   Application are redeployed in-place.

AFAIK, this apply to the production mode too. So it must be a syntax problem in the command you use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that the problem is the "production" mode, that it should prevent the JSP refresh.

Tomcat disables the JSP refresh in production mode too.

Regards.