# Deploying new jars to weblogic 9.2 without restart

Tags: weblogic9.x

I am have to develop an application based on Spring AOP that adds trace Id and loggers to existing application in live production.

The new aop application needs to be packaged onto jars and is to be deployed on code in production. But the production code is running on weblogic server and I don't have option to stop the already running weblogic servers.

Can any body help or give me the clue on how to introduce this new jar to the running application on weblogic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit late , but i found this question while searching for the same thing.
The `nostage` mode can help you with this,I tried it for JSP's and it works great , not sure about the jars though
These links are useful , they might help --
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/deployment/deploy.html#wp1024366

[How do I refresh jsp's on weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476461/how-do-i-refresh-jsps-on-weblogic)