# How to deploy single changed JSP on weblogic without restart

Tags: web, weblogic

I have big web app on weblogic. I am doing client side development. Every time i make some ui element changes I need to redeploy the whole web app to see the changes. This web app takes 20 minutes to get deploy. Is there smart way to just deploy the single JSP like we can do in tomcat ?

Comment: This question has been already answered - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476461/how-do-i-refresh-jsps-on-weblogic  Do a little research before posting.

Comment: It does not answer this question. I went through the answer it does not help at all ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to set your application to `nostage` mode. This will allow it to automatically detect changes to JSPs. `stage` mode copies the application to each individual server and does not automatically detect changes, it is probably what your application is defaulting to.

See more here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/deployment/deploy.html#wp1024366

Comment: nonstage requires restarting as i my changes are not affecting before restart.Are you sure sir ?

Answer (score 0):

C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\TOMS_DOMAIN_NEW\servers\AdminServer\tmp_WL_user\cms\mf3i5c\war\cms\web-inf

you can find your domin name in user_projects. and copy your jsp in web-inf.